# Mobile broadband: tries to connect, disconnects before being done

Tags: networking, broadband

I added this connection via the wizard:

- Connection name: movistar (I am in Spain)
- Connect automatically: unchecked
- IPv4 Settings tab:

  - method: automatic (PPP)
  - Addresses, DNS servers, Search domains: empty/grayed/disabled fields
  - Routes...: all empty
- Mobile Broadband tab:

  - Number: *99#
  - Username: movistar
  - Password: movistar
  - APN: movistar.es
  - Network ID: empty
  - Type: Any
  - Allow roaming if home network is not available: checked
  - PIN: 4 digits (triple checked)
- PPP Settings:

  - Authentication: EAP, PAP, CHAP, MSCHAPv2, MSCHAP
  - Configure Methods: all checked
  - Use point-to-point encryption (MPPE): unchecked
  - Allow BSD data compression: checked
  - Allow Deflate data compression: checked
  - Use TCP header compression: checked
  - Send PPP echo packets: unchecked

In the connections systray widget, "Enable mobile broadband" is checked, when i click on "Movistar" in a couple of seconds a popup says: "Modem network: disconnected". It's my first time and the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.10/internet/C/connecting-mobile.html) is helpless. Any idea is welcome!

- Ubuntu 11.10 oneiric.
- Device is an [Ubuntu-certified](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/make/usb:413C/index.html?start=50&batch=50) Vostro V131 laptop SIM card slot behind the battery: Bus 002 Device 007: ID 413c:818d Dell Computer Corp.
- Provider is movistar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simcard must first be activated.